# How to inject certain context into all pages in Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby

Using `gatsby-node.js` and `createPages` I can query *something* using graphql and create pages using that *something* as page context. So those pages can use that *something* as parameter in their queries.

The problem I'm facing is that I don't want to use `createPages`. I'm completely fine with pages that are created by default (from `gatsby-plugin-page-creator`), I just want all of them to have *something* from graphql as a context.

**Basically I want a global context (which I get from gatsby graphql) to be available for all pages.**

There is `onCreatePage` hook but unfortunately graphql is not available there according to https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3121#issuecomment-348781341.

Comment: As far as I know, what you are trying to achieve isn't possible yet. Page query is receiving its args from context which is set within `createPages` call in `gatsby-node.js`. And you cannot directly pass args to it (via expression interpolation) due to the way Gatsby parses `graphql` tagged templates.

Comment: i am facing the same challenge, i think i'll use a static page query in the root template.

Answer (score 1):

What about this... you can try using the **onCreateNode()** hook instead inside your `gatsby-nodejs` file. E.g.:

```
const allMyPageNodes = [];

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions;
  if(...) { //whatever filtering you need to select JUST pages in your site
    const mySpecialContext = "blah"; //whatever your global context settings are
    createNodeField({ node, name: "myglobal", value: mySpecialContext });
    allMyPageNodes.push(node);
  }
}
```

```

Then in all graphql queries thereafter, for pages, the graphql payload should have *edge.node.fields.myglobal* populated and you should be able to do whatever you like with it. Also have a look at https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/ for querying directly from inside a component.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Unfortunately it won't work for me because the context that I need also should come from graphql, and I can't use graphql inside onCreateNode. Moreover, I need to be able to use this context as parameter for page query, not as payload.

Comment: Take a look at that method https://v3.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/#setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType